# All Products disappear after Deleting ANYONE from Cart

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, w3-total-cache

I m having a weird problem, It was working all well, Suddenly, what happened is that if I add Two or more products in my cart and THEN Delete any ONE, all the products disappear from the cart. After I reload/refresh the page, the REST of the products (not Deleted one) come back again. The same goes for the other products.

At first I thought it has to do with W3 Total cache plugin, so I disabled it. Then I disabled Minify in Cloudfare CDN. Then disabled all the plugins in wordpress. Then I switched to Twenty Seventeen Theme- ALL WENT IN VAIN. I have no idea what is messing with this, I doubt its javascript. What do I do now. Plz check the problem [Here](https://gyazo.com/4abd919fdde681665d1f1fceb2779ccc). I was just a day away from making this site live.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can be much help if we don't even have a way to debug actual code... ;)

Comment: thank u, but I fixed it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After spending one hour I finally fixed it. Who knows that a single setting will mess this whole things up. As soon as I changed the *"HTTP Referrer Policy"* to 'no referrer when downgrade(browser default)' , the problem got fixed. 
I have no idea how it messed up with my javascript.**